# Sending Discord embeds with repeated pattern but different content more optimally

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm hosting a Discord Bot which prints out advice against each characters in a game (it responds with '%character'). It then sends a embed message with all the information and tips for that specific character.

That's a whole lot of information, the way I handle it right now is this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const command = require("./command");
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json", "utf8"));
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("message", () => {
// People will use different names for one character, that's why I have multiple aliases here
command(bot, (aliases = ["xy", "xyz", "x"]), (message) => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("X vs. Y Advice")
      .setURL("insert document link here")
      .setAuthor("myself", "serverlogo")
      .attachFiles(["./HeadIcons/CharacterHead.png"])
      .setThumbnail("attachment://CharacterHead.png")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter("The bot was written by me", "serverlogo")
      .setColor("#E42E29")
      .addFields(
        {
          name: "Notes:",
          value: "Insert advice here",
        },
        {
          name: "Stages:",
          value: "Insert stages to pick/ban here",
        },
        {
          name: "Documents:",
          value: "document links",
        },
        {
          name: "Videos:",
          value: "gameplay footage",
        },
        {
          name: "Other:",
          value: "other resources",
        }
      );

    message.channel.send(embed);
  });

// Repeat command for other characters

});
```

You can find the command.js code here: https://hatebin.com/upkyqvnujf

I have multiple questions here:
What'd you recommend for storing this data?
I've read JSON is not very secure but the data I want to store isn't sensitive or anything.

Is there a better way for handling each command? I'm repeating the command section for each individual character, which is just over 3000 lines of code, and it's not very optimal.

The bot is running 24/7 on a VPN server (Ubuntu), are the alternatives to updating the bot other than replacing the files directly via FileZilla individually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What'd you recommend for storing this data?

I would recommend that you use an SQLite database using `better-sqlite3` due to its faster nature. [Check out the npm package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3). The docs are easy to understand, although it may take some working out at times.

> Is there a better way for handling each command?

If there is alot of data about the characters, you could always use a command handler over multiple files. This way the code would be split between many files, and would be a bit less stressful for your bot to handle.

> Are there alternatives to updating the bot other than replacing the files directly via FileZilla individually?

You can setup a github repo, and setup a command within your bot to pull from the repo and add the changes to the bot's code directly. From what I hear its challenging, but it does work. Alternatively, you could have a dev bot hosted locally where you build code, then submit it manually - saving time and cutting down on irritating filezilla logins.